# JavaScript Error: caught (in promise) TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property

Tags: javascript, javascript-proxy

I'm attempting to add an "eventlistener" of sorts to trigger when all of the application resources have completed loading. If I understand Proxies correctly, "this is the way" to monitor object property changes. The following code works in my jsfiddle by itself, but when put into use with the actual code that loads actual resources I get the error: "caught (in promise) TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property". I'm new to JavaScript Proxies in general, so even any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

```js
const log = console.log.bind(console);

let gameState = {
  live: false,
  loading: {
    images: false,
    sounds: false,
    controls: false,
  },
};

const loadingListener = {
  set(obj, prop, value) {
    Reflect.set(...arguments);
        if (gameState.loading.images &&
        gameState.loading.sounds &&
        gameState.loading.controls) {
      log(true);
    } else {
      log(false);
    }
  },
};

// Create the proxy object with the original object and the handler
const proxyObject = new Proxy(gameState.loading, loadingListener);

// Test the proxy object
proxyObject.images = true;
proxyObject.sounds = true;
proxyObject.controls = true;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly shows the issue when directly run.

Comment: I can't... my code is loading actual img/audio resources; I guess I am wondering if my implementation of a JavaScript proxy is correct?